# Understanding PyTorch's BCE Notation

Tags: deep-learning, classification, pytorch, binary

According to the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html) for the Binary Cross Entropy Loss, we can write it as follows:

$$l_{n} = -w_{n}\cdot \left[y_{n}\cdot \log \left(x_{n}\right) + \left( 1-y_{n}\right)\cdot \log\left( 1-x_{n}\right) \right].$$

What do the $w_{n}$, $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation of the `BCELoss` you will the that they mean the following:

- $w$ is the weight to use, by which the loss will be rescaled.
- $x$ is the output value, which is the value that is predicted by the model.
- $y$ is the target value, which is the ground truth value.